# Dax Equation to identify Duplicates in a Table Column

Tags: duplicates, dax

I am looking to identify duplicate values in one column in a table.
I added a Column with name Unique_Ctr and have this formula.

Unique_Ctr =
COUNTROWS(FILTER('EnergyRoster',EARLIER('EnergyRoster'[NameID])-'EnergyRoster'[NameID])
)

I get the error, "Cannot convert value 'JorgeCordon' of type Text to type Number."
JorgeCordon is a value in the Column that I am trying to analyze for duplicates

Comment: Please show input data in text format and desired output. BTW, EARLIER() is effectively deprecated now we have VAR

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: are you still needing help with this Jim?